# install Appserv with Ms sql server in one system

Tags: appserver

Is it possible to install "Appserv" (Containing PHP, MySQL, phpmyadmin, apache web server) into a system that already has IIS, MS Sql server 2008, ASP.NET and visual studio 2010 installed?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can install Appserv along with the IIS stuff. You will deal with virtual server definitions to have both running at the same time especially both are trying to serve html on port 80.